Can Jmeter be configured to report latency in microseconds or fractions of millisecond?
Is it anyway to configure jmeter to report latency in microseconds alt fractions of millisecond vs integer milliseconds?
Doing low latency benchmarking and when latency is sub ms it is reported as 0ms which  impacts reported throughput aggregates etc.

As of JMeter 5.6 it's not possible so you either need to raise an enhancement request or implement it yourself and build JMeter
Alternatively you can create your own JMeter plugin which will be running requests and report latency with micro or nano seconds precision.

There is commented lines in jmeter.properties file:
# Whether to use System.nanoTime() - otherwise only use System.currentTimeMillis()
#sampleresult.useNanoTime=true

logically if you'll uncomment this option, the nano should give more sub-millisecondary response, basically you'll have higher resolution in JMeter results.

it's true by default

As it supposed to be, it's just commented and needs to be uncommented not to use currentTimeMillis by default instead.
Or if it not provided in .properties it can be added:
Example: https://sarkershantonu.github.io/blog/configuring-jmeter-part-5-how-to/

Unfortunately the  sampleresult.useNanoTime  param doesn't change the way latency is reported in the result file.
